# Странное поведение Perl Regexp (не ищет 2 раза)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Имеем  perl v5.10.1 CentOs 6.10.
Как можно объяснить такое поведение регулярных выражений в Perl

```
my $text = "Hello olleH";
$text =~ /olleH/g;
print $&."\n";
$text =~ /Hello/g;
print $&."\n";
```

при выполнении этого кода поиск происходит только в первом выражении, ответ:

> olleH olleH

Но если их поменять местами то тогда срабатывают обе

```
my $text = "Hello olleH";
$text =~ /Hello/g;
print $&."\n";
$text =~ /olleH/g;
print $&."\n";
```

> Hello olleH

Можно еще убрать в первом коде ключ **g** тогда тоже получаем что нужно.
Такое впечатление что в первом варианте поиск доходит до конца строки и во втором начинать с начала не хочет. Я где то просмотрел и подобное поведение логично?

Comment: Как минимум описано в документации про ключ g

Comment: Спасибо конечно за "глубокий" комментарий, но не могли бы вы немного расширить объяснение. Потому что я про него читал, но доменя так видимо и не дошло в чем подвох. g - находит все найденные подстроки;

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl Global Matching

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понял. Просто на русском ничего внятного не находил видимо.

Answer (score 1):

Модификатор регулярных выражений `g`, будучи примененным в скалярном контексте, запоминает позицию в анализируемой строке на которой остановился. И при следующем применении начинает поиск с этой позиции.

Для получения или изменения текущей позиции может быть использована функция `pos()`:

```
my $text = "Hello olleH";
$text =~ /olleH/g;
print $&,"\n","Pos: ".pos($text), "\n";
pos($text)=undef; # <-- Сбрасываем позицию
$text =~ /Hello/g;
print $&,"\n","Pos: ".pos($text), "\n";
```

Результат:

```
olleH
Pos: 11
Hello
Pos: 5
```